# How to store tinder on a hike?

Tags: wild-camping, fire-starting

What do people use to carry tinder whilst hiking? I was thinking of using a tobacco tin but on a multiday hike I'm not sure it will fit enough or if it will keep dry.

Tinder I would be using would be natural, things like silver birch bark and thistle seeds.

Comment: might be obvious, but still: what do you mean by DTI?
http://www.acronymfinder.com/DTI.html

Comment: @Akabelle good question, this was an autocorrect on my phone - meant to say dry

Comment: Have you tried dryer lint? Where I camp there's always an abundance of old man's beard/witches hair, so there's no need to bring tinder, but dryer lint is something that everyone has in abundance, and you can pack a lot of it into a zip lock bag and save on weight.

Comment: @ShemSeger that's a really cool idea, however I don't have a dryer!

Comment: @ChrisJ There's a never ending supply at every laundromat. It's not hard to come by. I'm sure you've got some friends or relatives who have a dryer, just raid their lint tray next time you visit.

Comment: @ShemSeger I'll definitely be on the lookout for dryers in the future - not as many people have them in the UK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a bigger tin box (it is left from an old [Str8 perfume](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjY1WDg5NA==/z/3aIAAOSwpDdVDoS8/$_35.JPG)), and within that I put the things in ziplock bags.

Comment: I hadn't thought about individually bagging the items inside, that makes much more sense

Comment: SWMBO cosmetics, never ending source for small boxes and containers... many of them seal perfectly...